# Bin packing java codes

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, optimization, bin-packing

For bin packing problem it might be easy to find the number of bins using different algorithms. Thus there should be an way to determine the weights have been fit in a particular bin.

The function below returns the number of bin using First Fit Algorithm. How can I return the each bin information (which bin contain which weights) ?
Thanks in advance :)

```
public String firstFit(int[]listWeight, int capBin) {

    int res = 0;
    // Initialize result (Count of bins)
    // Create an array to store remaining space in bins
    // there can be at most n bins
    int size=listWeight.length;
    int[] bin_rem= new int[size];

    // Place items one by one

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
           // Find the best bin that ca\n accomodate
           // weight[i]
           int j;

           // Initialize minimum space left and index
           // of best bin
           int min = capBin+1, bi = 0;

           for (j=0; j<res; j++)
           {
               if (bin_rem[j] >= listWeight[i] &&
                        bin_rem[j] - listWeight[i] < min)
                {
                    bi = j;
                    min = bin_rem[j] -listWeight[i];
                }
            }

            // If no bin could accommodate weight[i],
            // create a new bin
            if (min==capBin+1)
            {
                bin_rem[res] = capBin - listWeight[i];
                res++;
            }
            else // Assign the item to best bin
                bin_rem[bi] -= listWeight[i];

        }   
    return "Number of bin needed: "+res+";

}
```

// the codes, where I tried to return a string with all the bin's information.

```
public class Bin {

private int space;
private int [] attribute;


public Bin () {

}


public int getSpace() {
    return space;
}


public void setSpace(int space) {
    this.space = space;
}


public int getAttribute(int a) {
    return attribute[a];
}


public void setAttribute(int[] attribute) {
    this.attribute = attribute;
}

public void addAttribute(int a, int b) {
    this.attribute[a]=b;
}
```

}

// function

```
public  String firstFit(int weight[], int cap ){
    int count=0,i,j;
    int len=weight.length,space;
    Bin [] bin= new Bin[len];

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        bin[i].setSpace(cap);
        for (j=0;j<len;j++) {
            space=bin[j].getSpace();
            if (space >= weight[i]) {
                bin[j].addAttribute(j, weight[i]);
                bin[j].setSpace(space-weight[i]);
                count=j+1;
            }
        }
    }
    StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();
    rs.append(" Number of bin needed :  "+ count );
    for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
        rs.append("Bin ["+i+1+"]'s weights : ");
        for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
            rs.append(bin[i].getAttribute(j)+"  |");
        }
    } 
    String ms=rs.toString();
    return ms;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried with a bin class with two attributes like remaining capacity(int) and weights(int[]). Then I created an array of bin class and tried to play with it. But it doesn't work so far. 

{}

Comment: well you gotta show the code that doesn't work, else we can not fix it

Comment: I have added the codes. Can you check the question section.

Comment: Why do you have two `firstFit()` methods? What do you mean by return which bins contain which weights?

Comment: first one is the simple one where I returned the number of bins. In the second one, I have tried to return number of bins along with their weights, they hold.